# Формат даты в PHP

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Задача вывести дату следующего дня после 12:00 и не учитывать воскресенье с помощью php

Например:

сейчас 2021-11-04 11:00 - должно отображать 2021-11-04
сейчас 2021-11-04 12:30 - должно отображать 2021-11-05

и с воскресеньем:

сейчас 2021-11-06 12:30 (суббота) - должно отображать 2021-11-08 (понедельник)

Сделал так, отображается дата следующего дня, а вот как добавить отсчет от 12:00 и исключить из расчета воскресенье не пойму как сделать.

```
$data['date_shipment'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// текущее ыремя
$date = time();
// после полудня - прибавляем день
if (date('H:m', $date) > '12:00') {
    $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date);
}
// вс - прибавляем день
if(! date('w', $date)) {
        $date = strtotime("+1 day", $date);
}

print(date('r', $date));
```

Comment: в субботу прибавлять надо 2 дня

Comment: там два раза прибавится, если после 12

Comment: а, да, пардон =)